# Не запускается сборка из массива байт: BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net

```
Assembly exeAssembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
var entryPoint = exeAssembly.EntryPoint;
var parms = exeAssembly.CreateInstance(entryPoint.Name);
entryPoint.Invoke(parms, null);
```

Не запускается exe прочитанное в массив байт, выкидывая исключение

> System.BadImageFormatException: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "594432 bytes loaded from WindowsFormsApp7, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат."

В чем причина может быть? Версии менял, exe точно рабочий.

Comment: Ну и????????????

Comment: Ах, да. В чем причина может быть? Версии менял, exe точно рабочий.

Comment: Это исключение может выкинуто в случае, если сборка, которую вы загружаете, имеет неверный формат (например сборка неуправляемая) или требует версию CLR выше, чем целевая

Comment: А есть возможность любые запустить?

Comment: Можете указать задачу, которую нужно выполнить? Если просто нужно запустить exe, то проще его записать его в файл и запустить процесс.

Comment: Сорить не хочу тоннами файлов

Comment: Если тонны файлов запускаются одновременно, то проблемы будут с оперативной памятью, а не с дисковым пространством. Если не одновременно, то их можно чистить по завершении.

Comment: Я все прекрасно понимаю